# Stacking LineSeries - Ordered Data requirement

Tags: ios, shinobi, stacked-chart

I am plotting 7 time series using a LineSeries and I want to stack them. I am getting the same exception as is described on the Shinobi forum on the page linked below.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      
    0x0464c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     
    0x0315d8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
```

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/forum/shinobicontrols/2013/12/crash-under-ios-7-with-schartcolumnseries-stackindex-property

The solution as described in the answer is as follows:

> "If you are stacking series, you now need to ensure that the x values
>   of your series (or y values for vertical series) are in ascending
>   order."

My problem is that I don't understand this. My x-values are dates ordered from past to present. My y-values are count values. 
What & how am I supposed to order exactly? 
The only thing left to order are my y-values.

If I order my y-value does that mean my x-values (dates) will be unordered and the chart algorithm will put them together?

I just can't get me head around it :-(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing the right thing, in ordering your data points so that the x values are in ascending chronological order, so I'm not sure why you're getting this error.

Could you send over your project, or a sample project which replicates the problem? Once we can replicate it at this end, we should be able to pinpoint what is going wrong. You can email us at info@shinobicontrols.com.

Could you also let us know which version of ShinobiCharts you're building against?

Many thanks,

Dan